# python - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python

Was watching the MS tutorial ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljvCnjtnNkU)) mentioned below, getting the following error:

line 17
sample()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

=== Code below ===

```
def logger(func):
     def wrapper():
        print('Logging execution')
        func()
        print('Done Logging')

@logger
def sample():
    print(' -- Inside sample function')

sample()
```

[Image of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofdMv.png)

Comment: `logger` needs to return `wrapper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply forgot to return the inside function from the decorator. Add `return wrapper` to the end of `logger()`, and your code will work.